# Netsuite UI: Adding a Custom Address Dropdown to Sales Order

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

has anyone figured out how to have a custom drop down on a sales order of the customer addresses.

When creating the custom field on a Sales Order, you will notice that when you select Address or Address Book, the **FILTER USING** fields do not show. Only 'country' shows when you select **Address** and nothing shows when you select **Address Book**

So to Recap:

- I need to create a custom address drop-down field on a sales order that contains all of the customer addresses

Comment: Is your context the NS UI or on a NS hosted website?

Comment: Netsuite User interface. using scripting is not an option

Comment: You're a bit hosed if you can't use suitescript. @todd-grimm 's answer is the rough outline of how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

It might seem like more work than its worth, but if you build it properly you should be able to re-use this code anywhere else you want the ability to add custom address selection drop downs.

- In your before load script user event script you will want to add a new custom field of type 'select'.
- To populate the values do a search against the customer record and grab the address fields you need (if this is a new record and the customer isnt set in the before load, you can pass this off to the client script by making a selection called 'REFRESH' or something similar that triggers a post sourcing function to make the update to the field select options).
- Make sure to get at least the 'addressinternalid' and the 'addresslabel' fields from the customer (you will likely want them all just in case). Add the results to an array so that you can loop through it to build your custom field select options.

From there it would just be a matter of getting the user's selection and tying it to the correct address based on internal id.

I know I did not provide any specific code examples, but that would be your part of the game to play. Hope this helps, and good luck!